# fdisk -l ouputs nothing

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, fdisk

I have a dedicated server at 1and1. If I try to boot normally the server never initializes and I'm unable to contact it either by ssh or serial console. I can only reach it if I boot in rescue mode.

It is unclear to me what precisely is "rescue mode". However, [their instructions](http://faq.1and1.co.uk/server/root_server/linux_recovery/8.html) state that I should first run `fsdisk -l`. The output is empty:

```
rescue:~# fdisk -l
rescue:~#
```

Everywhere I've read it says this might be a very nasty problem.

Now, I don't mind bringing up my server from backups, but I want to find out if the disks are faulty. What should I do?

This is the output of `df -h`

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                   10M  132K  9.9M   2% /dev
tmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
rootfs                310M  259M   52M  84% /
```

This was it before my problems (you can see more diagnostics from a [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/392102/var-is-using-91-4-of-3-99gb-in-new-ubuntu-dedicated-server-from-1and1/392113#392113)):

```
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              3.7G  736M  3.0G  20% /
udev                   3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                  1.6G  260K  1.6G   1% /run
none                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                   3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /run/shm
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr   4.0G 1007M  2.9G  26% /usr
/dev/mapper/vg00-var   4.0G  3.7G  145M  97% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-home  4.0G  251M  3.6G   7% /home
```

It's on LVM by the way.

Comment: If you don't see _any_ drives, you should be contacting 1&1.

Comment: I've been through hell with their technical support, they keep on passing the problem to me. I'll try it again.

Comment: Looks like the kernel module for the SATA controller is missing in the initrd. Or /sys is not mounted (error in `fstab`?).

Answer (score 2):

A "rescue mode" is a live system booted via PXE. It resides in a ramdisk and you can mount your harddisk partitions to access your data.

In your case, if you don't see any harddisks via `fdisk -l`, this is probably a hardware problem (harddisk or cable), so you should have 1&1 check this.